# Splash Screen Painting Slow in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt, splash-screen, graphics2d

I am a Beginner in Java GUI, I am trying to show the user a splashScreen which will show him/her the Progress done, I  tried doing it with Graphics2D, but the problem is that the class paints the screen very slowly,
I did it using a for loop for animations but even without using the Thread.sleep() function the for loop is even slowed,
Here is my code:

```
int wpro = 0,prox = 491, proy = 389;
Graphics2D pro1 = splash.createGraphics();
pro1.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
pro1.setPaintMode();
pro1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
pro1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
wpro = 52;
for (int i = 0; i <= wpro; i++) {
    pro1.drawRect(prox, proy, i, 4);
    splash.update();
}
```

If anyone can help me out either by giving me an alternate way or pointing out my mistake.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Once again, post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: As shown in the answer to [How to Undo the splash screen painting in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436920/how-to-undo-the-splash-screen-painting-in-java), you're not using `CLEAR` correctly; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17414933/230513)

Comment: since i am not able to check this out. i am really thankful to you for your help and will try to check it soon.

Comment: can you please give me the comment as your answer so that after checking i can accept that answer.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11492697/1133011) example too.

Comment: As I said I am a Beginner, I cannot understand how to use clear here, I added following code into the for loop in above example

Comment: pro.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);  
    pro.fillRect(prox, proy, i-1, 6);  
    pro.setPaintMode();  
    pro.setColor(Color.WHITE);  
    pro.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

Comment: Graphics2D color compositions is also very slow.

Comment: @arynaq do you have an alternate